# Why is it bad to use data types to initialize instances in Python?

Tags: class, attributes, python

Sorry if the answer to this is obvious, but I want to be sure, if you have(in Python):

```
class Name(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.int_att1 = 0
        self.int_att2 = 0
        self.list_att = []
```

why can't(I know you can, but I've never seen a programmer do this) you initialize it in this way:

```
class Name(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.int_att1 = int
        self.int_att2 = int
        self.list_att = list
```

Are there bad effects that come out of this?
What makes the former more Pythonic?

My best guess is because Python needs a value for *instance.attribute*. But if this is the case than why is it that using *datatype* works?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer that works for you (click on the green checkmark by the one you like best).  You should do this for your other questions, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `self.int_att1 = int`, the attribute `int_att1` now references to the **type**  `int`, I mean, is just another name for `int`. And I'll prove this in a simple way:

```
>>> number_type = int
>>> i = number_type()
>>> i
0
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
```

In this code, `number_type` becomes a "synonym" for the type `int`, that's why when I asked the type of `i`, it returned `int` and not `number_type`.

Same for `self.list_att = list`.

---

Probably, what you wanted to do was:

```
class Name(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.int_att1 = int()
        self.int_att2 = int()
        self.list_att = list()
```

This is totally different, you are not longer assigning the type to the attribute. Instead, you are assigning the initial value of that type. Let's see what those initial values are:

```
>>> initial_int = int()
>>> initial_int
0
>>> initial_list = list()
>>> initial_list
[]
```

So, we can clearly see that the initial value of the type `int` is `0` and the initial value of the type `list` is `[]`, and that is exactly what you were looking for!

Comment: This answer is awesome. One more thing though, is this considered bad practice?

Comment: which one? `self.int_att1 = int` or `self.int_att1 = int()`?

Answer (score 2):

You *can*, but it has a totally different effect.  In the second case, you're setting the attribute equal to the value of the type, which is usually not what you want.  In Python types are objects too, so this is legal.

It would let you do something like:

```
n = Name()

v = n.int_att1()
```

`v` would then be 0, because that's the value constructed by `int`'s no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Explicit is better than implicit."

You could certainly initialize with the default value of a type (not the type itself as in your example), but explicit is better than implicit. When you initialize with an actual value, there's no doubt about what you're getting.